# How do I get Google Docs to use a French dictionary?

Tags: google-docs, localization, translation

I have Google Docs that are written in French. I've changed the language (File>Language>French) and this helps with spelling check and autocorrect.  But I'd also like to use the  *Define* feature to get the dictionary definition of a French word.

I have French included in my Google account General settings for the web - but the Define feature only recognises English words.

Here is an example doc:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Mh07SViV-1GRNta6kK3nLPA-hvGY6MjZ39JVfr3D90w/edit

Try the word "gouvernement".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Here is a doc that illustrates this for me.  For example, right click on the word "gouvernement" and select "Define".  I get no Dictionary results for this.    https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Mh07SViV-1GRNta6kK3nLPA-hvGY6MjZ39JVfr3D90w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I did several tests and I experienced the same behavior as you.  Didn't matter my settings, browser logged in or out, personal vs Workspace account, etc., etc. The French words that are defined are limited to ones that are used commonly in English (false positive). I had the same experience with tests in Spanish.  Spell-checking appears to work properly. There are a number of threads online complaining about this without resolution. I don't have a solution at this time. I also changed my Google language, browser language, and OS as well to see if anything made a difference. Nothing did.

Comment: Thanks for your investigations - much appreciated